# Component initially mounting with value of null for variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

This component was working fine before. I'm not exactly sure what I did to mess this up. But when the component initially mounts, the value of `artist` is null. Then - almost immediately - it is assigned to the object I expect. But before that happens I get a an error:

> Cannot read property activePreview of null

[image]

When I dismiss the error, the data renders correctly on the screen. So not sure why I'm getting this error at all.

[image]

Any ideas why this error is suddenly popping up? Or why `artist` is initially `null`?

```js
componentDidMount = () => {
    // Get the uids of all artists user follows
    db.ref(`users/${this.props.uid}/following`).once('value', (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot, index) => {
        var id = childSnapshot.val().uid;
        // For each of those ids, check if the artist has an active preview
        db.ref(`users/${id}`).once('value', (snapshot) => {
          const artist = snapshot.val();
          console.log(artist);
          // If they do, add them to the activePreviews array
          if (artist.activePreview) {
            this.setState({activePreviews: this.state.activePreviews.concat(artist)})
          }
        })
      })
    })
  }
```